# how to open the gallery?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to open the images gallery via code in my app.(only opening the gallery, the user is not going to select any image). I searched and found lots of ways but some of them worked only for selecting an image and other ways never worked.e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);
```

or

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
 "content://media/internal/images/media")); 
 startActivity(intent);
```

how may I open the gallery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void pickPhoto(View view) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
    }
```

Here:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                     data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Uri curImageURI = data.getData();
             Bitmap bit = getRealPathFromURI(curImageURI);
             imageView.setImageBitmap(bit);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
```

and

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        android.database.Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null,
                null, null);
        int column_index;
        try {
            column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return null;
        }

    }
```

CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE is the final number in the "startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);" 
in this case '1' so you'd need to change it to 1 or declare it as a global variable

Comment: no new thing! when it opens the gallery, if I ckick on an image it doesn't open that image, it returns :(

Comment: You cant have it do that, you must handle the image yourself in the 'onActivityResult'

Comment: (only opening the gallery, the user is not going to select any image)

Comment: If the person is not selecting an image that's fine then?

Comment: `You cant have it do that, you must handle the image yourself in the 'onActivityResult'`, so it seems that this is the part where I need help. please complete your answer!